# How to close the bootstrap datepicker calander as soon as we click on the other bootstrap datepicker calander button

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

In our project we are using multiple calenders (bootstrap datepicker) with angularjs on the same form. The calender popup closes when we select a valid date but  in case if we do not select any date and click on the other calender button present on the same page(or form), the previous calander stays open. 
We want the previous calender to be closed as soon as we tab out or click any other button.

May i get some help in fixing this issue.
We are using different names for each date popup.

Comment: May you provide some code?

Answer (score 0):

**close multiple date picker when click another datepicker**

live code 
http://jsfiddle.net/RLQhh/1003/

```
 /****new min date code */
     $scope.dateChange = function(event){          
       var d= $scope.minDate1.setDate( $scope.dt.getDate() + 1);
       $scope.minDate1=new Date(d);
    }
     /****new min date code end */

  $scope.toggleMin = function() {
    $scope.minDate = $scope.minDate ? null : new Date();
       $scope.minDate1 = new Date();
  };
```

**html code**

```
<h4>Start Date</h4>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <p class="input-group">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" datepicker-popup="{{format}}" ng-model="dt" is-open="opened1" min-date="minDate" max-date="'2015-06-22'" datepicker-options="dateOptions" date-disabled="disabled(date, mode)" ng-required="true" ng-change="dateChange($event)"close-text="Close" />
              <span class="input-group-btn">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open1($event)"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></button>
              </span>
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <h4>End Date</h4>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <p class="input-group">
              <input type="text" ng-disabled="!dt" class="form-control" datepicker-popup="{{format}}" ng-model="dt2" is-open="opened2" min-date="minDate1" max-date="'2015-06-22'" datepicker-options="dateOptions" date-disabled="disabled(date, mode)" ng-required="true" close-text="Close" />
              <span class="input-group-btn">
                <button type="button" ng-disabled="!dt" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open2($event)"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></button>
              </span>
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
```